# How to enable ALL columns in windows file explorer (without select them all manually)?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, metadata

Is it possible to enable ALL columns in windows 10 file explorer at once?

I don't want to enable them one by one manually. I'm looking for some kind of registry entry or ready-to-use registry file.

*(Background: I need to find out which columns contains some specific metadata in our files)*

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Set Fldr=objShell.NameSpace(32)
Set Fldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(0))
Set FldrItems=Fldr.Items
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


Set DeskFldr=objShell.Namespace(16)
FName=fso.buildpath(DeskFldr.self.path, "Folder Property List.txt")


Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(FName, 8, true)



For x = 0 to 100
    t1 = t1 & Fldr.GetDetailsOf(vbnull, x) & vbtab
Next
ts.write FLDR.self.path & vbcrlf
ts.Write T1 & vbcrlf
T1=""


For Each FldrItem in FldrItems
    For x = 0 to 100
        t1 = t1 & Fldr.GetDetailsOf(FldrItem, x) & vbtab
    Next
    t1=t1 & vbcrlf
    ts.Write T1
    T1=""
Next

msgbox FName & "has a tab delimited list of all properties"
```

Call the above something.vbs.

Drag a folder on it to print out all properties to a file on the desktop.

EG

```
C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop\Editor
Name    Size    Item type   Date modified   Date created    Date accessed   Attributes  Offline status  Availability    Perceived type  Owner   Kind    Date taken  Contributing artists    Album   Year    Genre   Conductors  Tags    Rating  Authors Title   Subject Categories  Comments    Copyright   #   Length  Bit rate    Protected   Camera model    Dimensions  Camera maker    Company File description    Masters keywords    Masters keywords                        Program name    Duration    Is online   Is recurring    Location    Optional attendee addresses Optional attendees  Organiser address   Organiser name  Reminder time   Required attendee addresses Required attendees  Resources   Meeting status  Free/busy status    Total size  Account name        Task status Computer    Anniversary Assistant's name    Assistant's phone   Birthday    Business address    Business city   Business country/region Business P.O. box   Business postcode   Business county/region  Business street Business fax    Business home page  Business phone  Call-back number    Car phone   Children    Company main phone  Department  Email address   Email2  Email3  Email list  Email display name  File as First name  Full name   Gender  Given name  Hobbies Home address    Home city   Home country/region Home P.O. box   Home postcode   Home county/region  Home street Home fax    Home phone  
30122017.zip    35.5 MB Compressed (zipped) Folder  30/12/2017 9:59 AM  6/02/2021 2:25 PM   4/05/2021 10:09 AM  A           Compressed  LAPTOP\David Candy  Folder                              Unrated                                                                                                                                                     118 GB              LAPTOP (this PC)                                                                                                                                                                
Editor Shortcuts        File folder 6/02/2021 2:25 PM   6/02/2021 2:25 PM   12/08/2021 5:35 PM  D           Unknown LAPTOP\David Candy  Folder                              Unrated                                                                                                                                                     118 GB              LAPTOP (this PC)
```

---

**EDIT**

Open a folder, View ribbon Options - Folder and Search Options - View tab - Reset All Folders. Then tick each box you want and any other view settings you want. View ribbon Options - Folder and Search Options - View tab - Apply To Folders.

> From an old post of mine NB Registry paths have changed a number of times since then.
>
> You have to do Apply To All while in a file folder. For each type of
> object (File Folder, Control Panel, My Computer, etc) that you do an
> Apply to All in it's clsid and the settings are created/updated at
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams
> \Defaults
>
> {F3364BA0-65B9-11CE-A9BA-00AA004AE837} is ordinary folders, and other
> numbers are what ever they are (My Comp, Control Panel, etc - note My
> Docs is an ordinary folder). They only appear IF you do an apply to
> all in that type of object.
>
> as well as a higher set of defaults at
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams
> Settings=
>
> So the point being in the order that you do things. You want to do
> your overall default setting last. This is how I advised someone who
> asked
>
> > Can someone please tell me how to force Windows to keep
> > the seperate folder view settings I choose? I have
> > checked and rechecked the box in folder options for it to
> > remember, but it has no memory for that issue. To be more
> > specific; I want to always have the thumbnail view in My
> > Pictures and also in the Control Panel Dialog, but every
> > time I open them I have to manually set that view.
>
> Set Control Panel how you want then Tools - View - Apply To All
> Folders. This sets the global default and the Control Panel type of
> objects defaults (but the system default remains the same - it can't
> be changed but all other defaults/settings override it). Then go to an
> ordinary folder (as My Pics is for this feature) and set it how you
> want all folders but CP. Then Tools - View - Apply To All Folders.
> This sets the global default and the file folder type of object
> defaults (CP's default settings will still override the global). Then
> set My Pics how you want it and do nothing else as we are saving it by
> the checkbox Remember Folder Settings AND BY THE PATH WE GOT THERE. EG
> Opening a folder at *This PC* eg `This PC\C:\Windows` is a different set
> of settings to opening a folder at *C:* drive then `C:\Windows`.

The result of this is if when first using Explorer you always fix the view and it will remember exactly what you want and guess correctly for new stuff.

Comment: Thanks for this. Great approach. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work for pictures or music or video files (including metadata).

Comment: Thank you for your EDIT. As I initially wrote: I'm looking for a solution without manual "ticking each box you want".

Comment: You only tick them once.